# Compare two audio files in iOS

Tags: ios, signal-processing, audio-recording, audio-comparison

I want to record two voices and compare them. I think there is some Apple sample code for voice recording. I have no idea about 
comparing two audio files. What is the right approach for this? Is there any framework Apple provides for this purpose or is there any third party framework?

Answer (score 1):

It's not in objective C, but it does contain some fantastic explanation about how audio is compared by Shazam, and includes sample code (and source for a working application) in Java:

[Check this out](http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/)

Additionally, [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550927/how-to-compare-mp3-programmatically) has a fantastic link to audio fingerprinting, which is essentially the same as the article above, but more in depth.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visqol for this purpose. If your audio files are generally not more than 10sek this could be something worth looking into. Also check ffmpeg library for converting the files into the desired format(Visqol will require certain sample rate depending if it is just music or speech).
https://github.com/google/visqol