# comparing two audio files

Tags: objective-c

In my app i want to compare two sound files and find out if they are same or different. The flow is : User records two audio files, stores them to documents directory  , fetches them again for comparison and checks whether they are same or different. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968557/compare-two-audio-sounds-in-iphone